# Using pytorch cuda in AWS sagemaker notebook instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

In colab, whenever we need GPU, we simply click `change runtime type` and change hardware accelarator to `GPU`

and cuda becomes available, `torch.cuda.is_available()` is `True`

How to do this is AWS sagemaker, i.e. turning on cuda.
I am new to AWS and trying to train model using pytorch in aws sagemaker, where Pytorch code is first tested in colab environment.

my sagemaker notebook insatnce is `ml.t2.medium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWS Sagemaker you don't need to worry about the GPU, you simply select an instance type with GPU ans Sagemaker will use it. Specifically `ml.t2.medium` doesn't have a GPU but it's anyway not the right way to train a model.
Basically you have 2 canonical ways to use Sagemaker (look at the documentation and examples please), the first is to use a notebook with a limited computing resource to spin up a training job using a prebuilt image, in that case when you call the estimator you simply specify what [instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) you want (you'll choose one with GPU, looking at the costs). The second way is to use your own container, push it to ECR and launch a training job from the console, where you specify the instance type.

Comment: thanks! what instances have a GPU/how can i find out?

Comment: found it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html